# Могу ли я использовать PHPWord увеличить количество столбцов в таблице из шаблона?

Tags: php, шаблоны, phpword

Я знаю, что PHPWoord в "Templates processing" позволяет копировать текстовые блоки и строки в таблице.

Но есть способ легко увеличить количество столбцов в таблице, которая находится в шаблоне?